# CSS content fits but is bigger, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my webpage customized for cellphones. The problem is when i try to use the inspect tool for chrome and make the "screen" smaller the webpage looks smaller but the body element doesn't get smaller, according to the sinpect tool.
[Image showing the different images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkJMh.png)

This feels really wierd since their are no scroll sideways and in my opinion it should't fit if it was right.

Comment: Did you add the viewport meta tag on the head? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/ your content is probably zooming out instead of resizing

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Here `width` is the width of the virtual viewport of the device,`device-width` is the physical width of the device’s screen,`initial-scale` is the  initial zoom when visiting the page. 1.0 does not zoom.
Reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp